# i can't make works this easy code to run webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

i learn how to use webpack.
I wrote this code in my webpack.config.js

```
const path= require('path')

module.exports= {
    entry:'./app/assets/scripts/App.js',
    output: {
        filename:'bundled.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'App')
    },
    mode:'development',
    watch: true, 
};
```

I wrote this code in my package.json

```
 { 
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "devDependencies":{
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
 }
```

and this is the code in my App.js

```
alert("Hello, this is just a test!");
```

i run `npm run dev`. i get no errors messages, but the javascript don't run in my index page. Please help me, i don't understand from where the problem comes.

Comment: webpack doesn't run code. it bundles it.

Comment: Can you show us the code for your "index page"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of trying, 
it seems my index.html VisualCodeStudio started to now that bundled.js exist in proposing it via intellisens.
I delete also the main: index.js on my package.json.
Now its working, even if i didnt't yet clearly detected what was the problem initially.